# How to export table from DB using MYSQLWorkbench and import it on phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost

I'm having trouble exporting a table from MYSQLWorkbench and importing it to PHPMyAdmin.
So I can have a DB running on my localhost. I've searched everywhere for this sort of question but couldn't find anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Arnav.

Comment: MySQLWorkbench and PHPMyAdmin don't work with SQL Server; are you *sure* that's the RDBMS you are using? What is it you need help with? What have you tried, why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0):

**EXPORTING**

In MySQL Workbench go to the "server" tab where there is an option "Data export", you could choose which database to export from there. It will be saved as a .sql file in your local computer.
[MySQL Workbench Export image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqteY.png)

**IMPORTING**

In PHPmyadmin you can import this .sql file and use it on localhost
[Phpmyadmin Import image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYiwB.png)